# MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN Not Working In Android

Tags: java, android, touch-event

I programming an android app that use drag and zoom. But when I programming `Touch` class, `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`, `MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN` and `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` not working. How can fix my code?

Touch class:

```
private static final int NONE = 0;
private static final int DRAG = 1;
private static final int ZOOM = 2;

private static final float MAX_ZOOM = 3f;
private static final float MIN_ZOOM = 3f;

public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    int mode = NONE;
    float oldDistance = 1f;

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

    PointF start = new PointF();
    PointF mid = new PointF();

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)view;

    switch(event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
            mode = DRAG;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            oldDistance = spacing(event);
            if(oldDistance > 10f) {
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                midPoint(mid, event);
                mode = ZOOM;
            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            mode = NONE;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if(mode == DRAG) {
                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y);
            }
            else if(mode == ZOOM) {
                float newDistance = spacing(event);
                if(newDistance > 10f) {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    float scale = newDistance / oldDistance;
                    float[] values = new float[9];
                    matrix.getValues(values);
                    float currentScale = values[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
                    if(scale * currentScale > MAX_ZOOM) 
                        scale = MAX_ZOOM / currentScale;
                    else if (scale * currentScale < MIN_ZOOM) 
                        scale = MIN_ZOOM / currentScale;
                    matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                }
            }
            break;
    }
    imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
    return true;
}

private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {  
    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
 }

private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
    point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
 }
```

Comment: Please try to be more clear what the actual problem is. 'Not working' is a very vague explanation.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with the fact that your `MAX_ZOOM` and `MIN_ZOOM` values are equal?

Comment: I mean my event not enter to any `case` in `switch` (`MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`, `MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN` and `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE`)

Comment: Eric -> No, I test it with different values, but it's not working yet.

Comment: @Vahid Have you read this post: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html

Comment: If anyone knows how to apply this effect to a webview, please comment.

Answer (score 0):

is it so necessary to use a switch case statement? it may be easier for you to read, but when i do this >>

```
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

    }
```

it works just fine. Also, you should add log calls in you case statement to find out if your onTouch is being called, and which cases it does and does not go through. also you could log the values that are being passed in by the mask and the event code? those would all help.